# Kubuntu Panel ICON resizing problem

Tags: kubuntu, icons, kde

This question is for KDE users,

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I installed KDE 4.11.2 in Ubuntu, and everything seems fine.

But these icons get very small when I select SHOW a icon when not running. I have seen various bugs regarding this but haven't seen any solution to this problem

See this screenshot (Computer ICON on the panel)

[image]

I want this to be fixed , as this feels very tiny, before selecting, SHOW a icon when not running it was equal to chrome icon, given in the same screenshot.

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by upgrading to 4.11.3 and using plasma-widget smooth task bar. Will edit this after repeating steps and with  proper instructions.

Comment: finally, icon only task manager did the job.

Comment: Could you please accept your answer if this is how you solved the issue, and expand it with more detail to help others?

Answer (score 0):

There is no fix for this. The iconsize for a "show when not running" is smaller than the iconsize for a launcher. I'm not sure why the KDE devs did it this way though.